# Is a distance whose value is not defined possible? Bird and athlete problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

The question-

> There is an athlete running with a speed of $15\ \rm km/h$ towards the finish point.
>   When the runner is $7.5\ \rm km$ from the finish , a bird starts flying at the speed of $30\ \rm km/h$ from the athlete to finish point and then to the athlete and the again towards the finish point and repeats this process until the athlete reaches the finish point. Find the total distance travelled by the bird until the athlete reaches the finish point.

I tried  to solve it and but it's solution will never come in integer. It's solution is very near to $15$ but not exactly $15$ or any integer. So the answer to this question was that the bird travels a distance whose value is  not defined.

But if we practically do this experiment, will the bird travels a distance which is undefined?

Comment: Why is the distance the bird travels undefined unless the distance is an integer?

Comment: Is a half a pie an undefined quantity of pie?  Does it contain an undefined quantity of calories?   Can I eat two half-pies instead of one whole-pie to avoid putting on weight?

Comment: No what I wanted to say there ,was that every time  we solve it algebrically, we get closer and closer to 15. If you solve for the distance between the athlete and the finish point, every time we do it, we will get very close to zero but it is not possible to get absolute 0 distance between the athlete and the finish point

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to solve it by working out an infinite series, but this is actually a classic trick question. Here's the trick.

The runner is 7.5 km from the finish and running at 15km/h. Therefore, the total time before the runner reaches the finish is .5 h. The bird is traveling at 30 km/h continuously for that whole .5h, so it travels 15 km. We don't need to know the details of how far the bird goes on each "lap" because we can simply look at the whole time.

(As an aside -- why does it matter if the distance is not an integer?)

Comment: The distance needs to be an integer because integers are magical, just like this bird that can undergo instantaneous accelerations :)

Comment: This does not answer the question : *But if we practically do this experiment, will the bird travels a distance which is undefined?*

Comment: @sammygerbil You have to consider the context he asked that.  He says it's not defined because it does not reach an integer.  I think it's reasonable to show him a good way to actually get an integer, and question why a non-integer would be undefined.  Probably would have been better to wait for OP to clear it up though.

Comment: No what I meant was that the distance between the athlete and the finish point will never come zero if we solve it, it will be very close to zero and getting closer every time we solve it algebraically but never absolute zero

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of a "[supertask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask)", where there are an infinite number of operations. As zeldredge correctly points out one does not need to worry about the details here to solve it (the same solution method can be applied to solve the Zeno paradoxes). A more disturbing issue is in what direction the bird flies when the athlete crosses the finish line: this *is* indeterminate in the problem setting.

In practice all motion occurs within some measurement accuracy and more importantly, with finite accelerations, so the bird would be pointed in some definite direction having traversed a distance that could be measured at some finite precision.

One can of course bring up quantum mechanics to add further headaches: knowing the momentum and position of the bird is subject to the Heisenberg relations. In fact, one can make a quantum version of the problem: consider the wavefunction of a particle inside a box that is shrinking linearly with time. One can guessthat for a wave packet that is pretty localized it is going to be following the classical path until the box becomes similarly sized to its spread, upon which the particle becomes pretty delocalized and the momentum begins to diverge. Again, a real particle will not stay confined in a real box as the size goes to zero.